# when passing a variable into a backbone template, how to reference it in the template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

the Template looks like this.

```
<div>
    <H5>Status for your request</H5>
    <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>RequestId</th>
        <th><%=id%></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th><%=emailId%></th>
    </tr>       
    <tr>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th><%=status%></th>
    </tr>       
     </tbody>
     </table>
</div>
```

This is the View Javascript that renders the page.

```
window.StatusView = Backbone.View.extend({

initialize:function () {
    console.log('Initializing Status View');
    this.template = _.template(tpl.get('status'));
},

render:function (eventName) {

    $(this.el).html(this.template());
    return this;
},

events: { "click button#status-form-submit" : "getStatus" },

getStatus:function(){

    var requestId = $('input[name=requestId]').val();
    requestId= $.trim( requestId );

    var request  = requests.get( requestId );

    var statusTemplate = _.template(tpl.get('status-display'));
    var statusHtml = statusTemplate( request );
    $('#results-span').html( statusHtml );
}

});
```

When the clicks on the input, the requestId is read and the status is appended in html element with id 'results-span'.

The failure happens when replacing the values in html-template with variable values.

```
var statusTemplate = _.template(tpl.get('status-display'));
var statusHtml = statusTemplate( request );
```

The rendering fails with the following error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: emailId is not defined
(anonymous function)
_.templateunderscore-1.3.1.js:931
window.StatusView.Backbone.View.extend.getStatusstatus.js:34
jQuery.event.dispatchjquery.js:3242
jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandle
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Underscore's [`_.template`](http://underscorejs.org/#template):

> Compiles JavaScript templates into functions that can be evaluated for rendering.
>   [...]
>
> ```
> var compiled = _.template("hello: <%= name %>");
> compiled({name : 'moe'});
> => "hello: moe"
> ```

So basically, you hand the template function an object and the template looks inside that object for the values you use in your template; if you have this:

```
<%= property %>
```

in your template and you call the template function as `t(data)`, then the template function will look for `data.property`.

Usually you convert the view's model to JSON and hand that object to the template:

```
render: function (eventName) {
    $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
}
```

I don't know what your `eventName` is or what you're planning to do with it but you need to get an object with this structure:

```
data = { id: '...', emailId: '...', status: '...' }
```

from somewhere and hand that to the template function:

```
var html = this.template(data)
```

to get some HTML to put on the page.

Demo (with a fake model for illustrative purposes): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/hpSpf/

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. Instead of passing the Backbone model, I passed a pure javascript object that is created from the model.  `var data = { id : request.get('id'), emailId : request.get('emailId'), status : request.get('status') };` . Now template is rendering it fine. What is the difference between BackBone model and pure JS object?

Comment: @Nambi: Views usually display models or collections in Backbone and that model or collection is in [`this.model` or `this.collection`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-constructor). Then you translate the model/collection to a plain JavaScript data structure using the [`toJSON`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-toJSON) method. If `request` is a Backbone model then your `var data = { ... }` is the same as `var data = request.toJSON()` except that `toJSON` will include all the `request` attributes. The template does care, it just wants an object with the right keys.

Answer (score 3):

```
OptionalExtrasView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        // Get the product id
        //var productid = $( this ).attr( "productid" );
        var data = {name : 'moe'};

        var tmpl = _.template($('#pddorder_optionalextras').html() );
        this.$el.html(tmpl(data));
    }
});

   var search_view = new OptionalExtrasView({ el :     $('.pddorder_optionalextras_div')});
```

and just before the body tag:

```
      <script type="text/template" id="pddorder_optionalextras">
   <%= name %>
    </script>
```

Comment: I get this using Node.js,
Error message is---->  name is not defined

Comment: I think this is because I should be using EJS templating not underscore templating